# Weird issue occurring while testing Live data in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, observer-pattern, android-livedata, assertion

While testing LiveData through JUnit in Kotlin I am facing a weird issue in which Logs are showing expected and actual value exact similar but still Test Observer failing the test.

Below is the test and logs after running the test.

```
@Test
fun onSelectedAddressInfoTest_selected() {
    viewModel.selectedAddressInfo?.test()?.assertNoValue()
    viewModel.onAddressInfoSelected(AddressInfoStub.getValidStub())
    viewModel.selectedAddressInfo?.test()?.assertHasValue()
    //error is here 
    // viewModel.selectedAddressInfo?.test()?.assertValue(AddressInfoStub.getValidStub()) 
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: AddressInfo(id=1, imageUrl=image.com, description=Deliver to hukum, location=Location{address = 'place',lng = '12.999999',lat = '24.0'}) (class: AddressInfo)

Actual: AddressInfo(id=1, imageUrl=image.com, description=Deliver to hukum, location=Location{address = 'place',lng = '12.999999',lat = '24.0'}) (class: AddressInfo)

    at com.jraska.livedata.TestObserver.fail(TestObserver.java:268)
    at com.jraska.livedata.TestObserver.assertValue(TestObserver.java:105)
    at com.assessment.AddressInfobaseproject.ui.AddressInfoList.AddressInfoListViewModelTest.onSelectedAddressInfoTest_selected(AddressInfoListViewModelTest.kt:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: What does `getValidStub` return? Have you implemented a proper `equals` method?

Comment: This is nothing but providing DummyData for testing and assertion purpose. I have not done any equals implementation but relying on test().assertHasValue()

Comment: But is it providing a new instance every time? Try either to provide an `equals` implementation or store `AddressInfoStub.getValidStub()` as variable, using it in both places.